# Fastest way to read help on not installed program (I'm Feeling Lucky)

Tags: command-line, ux

What is the fastest way to lookup info on a program that is not currently installed?

Today I needed Ubuntu to remind me about some event, and I though that Ubuntu could be as smart as Google's `I'm Feeling Lucky` button. But unfortunately, that didn't work:

```
$ remind
The program 'remind' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install remind
$ man remind
No manual entry for remind
$ help remind
bash: help: no help topics match `remind'.  Try `help help' or `man -k remind'
or `info remind'.
```

Before installing I expected to check is remind is really what I need.

Of course `info remind` didn't help (no need to show it at all). `man -k` was not tool helpful either:

```
$ man -k remind
calendar (1)         - reminder service
```

And digging about what does it `man -k` mean was not successful too:

```
-k, --apropos              equivalent to apropos
```

So, how do you find needed apps from command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's also `dman` from the [bikeshed](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bikeshed/) package.

```
sudo apt-get install bikeshed
```

It lets you read manual pages from the internet, without the need of installing the corresponding packages:

```
dman remind
```

Comment: The only downside is that `bikeshed` contains way too much stuff. =)

Comment: @techtonik: agreed. However note that it has no dependencies (only recommended packages)

Comment: Strange. `apt-get install bikeshed` fetched 40Mb and 59 packages (including `vim` and `byobu`). Does Ubuntu install recommended packages by default?

Comment: @techtonik: yes, recommended packages are installed by default. Use `apt install --no-install-recommends` to avoid them

Answer (score 3):

1. Read the [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/remind.1.html) man pages.
2. Using `apt-cache`

   ```
   apt-cache show remind
   ```

   or

   ```
   apt-cache show remind | awk '/Description-en/ {print; a=1; next} a && /^ / {print; next} {a=0}'
   ```
3. Everything else is included in the package itself.

   ```
   apt-get download remind
   dpkg -x *.deb remind
   man ./remind/usr/share/man/man1/rem.1.gz
   ```

---

*Example output*

`apt-cache show remind`

```
Package: remind
Priority: optional
Section: universe/utils
Installed-Size: 411
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Ana Beatriz Guerrero Lopez <ana@debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Version: 03.01.15-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7)
Suggests: tkremind, wyrd
Filename: pool/universe/r/remind/remind_03.01.15-1_i386.deb
Size: 190964
MD5sum: e476e0b4e49a211ad860cde57b1b6ea5
SHA1: b342c7f05e560aecc3c7bac9aa1ae1fef424121c
SHA256: 67f34f03723e03653fc25d119b680da1ab03bf28fc78d80c2a173184cbf682bc
Description-en: sophisticated calendar and alarm program
 Remind allows you to remind yourself of upcoming events and
 appointments.  Each reminder or alarm can consist of a message sent
 to standard output, or a program to be executed.
 .
 It also features: sophisticated date calculation, moon phases,
 sunrise/sunset, Hebrew calendar, alarms, PostScript output, tcl/tk
 front-end and proper handling of holidays.
 .
 Reminders can be created by the remind scripting language or by using
 the graphical frontend package "tkremind".
Description-md5: 5b163d21d42fbc03e201fdb61071c10d
Homepage: http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/remind/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

`apt-cache show remind | awk '/Description-en/ {print; a=1; next} a && /^ / {print; next} {a=0}'`

```
Description-en: sophisticated calendar and alarm program
 Remind allows you to remind yourself of upcoming events and
 appointments.  Each reminder or alarm can consist of a message sent
 to standard output, or a program to be executed.
 .
 It also features: sophisticated date calculation, moon phases,
 sunrise/sunset, Hebrew calendar, alarms, PostScript output, tcl/tk
 front-end and proper handling of holidays.
 .
 Reminders can be created by the remind scripting language or by using
 the graphical frontend package "tkremind".
```

Comment: Is there some tool that is easier to remember and that doesn't show all this low level stuff?

Comment: I'd also expect a command line help on `remind` or some basic info how to use it.

Comment: Install `synaptic` for a better overview of the package details.

Comment: `synaptic remind` didn't work for me.